# Is it possible to do a "pen mode" using Kivy(+Python)?

Tags: android, python, kivy

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 8. When I use a tool like Autodesk Sketchbook, they have a "pen mode" that lets me ignore hand input, and only draw using the pen.

I'd like to duplicate this functionality, but I can't figure out how to do such a thing in Kivy.

According to a post on the Samsung Developers forum, it says that there's a `METASTATE_HAND` and `METASTATE_PEN`, and if I want to check the side button there's also a `getMetaState()`, and

> Value for stylus button pressed is `2560`

There's some information about `OnTouchListener` and `MotionEvent`, but I haven't been able to tease out of the Kivy docs whether or not that information is supported in Kivy (yet).

Is it possible to do such a thing in Kivy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the metastate is a property of the android MotionEvent. If kivy exposes this, it's probably available in the [touch profile](http://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.input.motionevent.html#profiles) of kivy's own motionevent (that is passed to on_touch_down etc.). If not, you could submit a feature request at the python-for-android github repository, this seems like a reasonable feature to have.

Normally for android api stuff you can use pyjnius, but I'm not sure if in this case there's a way to get this information since the MotionEvent is handled by the android bootstrap directly.

Comment: Looks like that's not available in the `MotionEvent`, so it's off to make a feature request I go!